# firestore query neutralized orderBy

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following query in Node.js:

```js
let q = db.collection('collectionName').orderBy('reg_dt', 'DESC').where('phone', '==', searchState.phone).limitToLast(60).get();
```

`orderBy(DESC)` Didn't work. When I wrote the same code without `limitToLast`, it did work. However, after adding `limitToLast`, `orderBy` reset to ascending.

I already created an index: index `reg_dt: DESC, phone: ASC`, but it said I should make `reg_dt: ASC, phone: ASC`. My client wants only `red_dt: desc`.

Is this an error? Or is there a way to force descending order?

Answer (score 1):

According to the official document regarding [ordering data in Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#node.js), to apply a descending order, you need to use `desc` lowercase instead of `DESC` capital:

```
db.collection('collectionName').orderBy('reg_dt', 'desc').where('phone', '==', searchState.phone).limitToLast(60).get();
//
```

Comment: Hey Jay. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?